# Asp.net, jQuery and dynamic content

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net site in which I create demo filed in a DataGrid by dynamic way.
Next, I have to check if a value in the quantity dynamic field is null or is not a number, or is negative, etc.

I would like to check it when I click on a send button, and I would like to use the jQuery script to do this; the question is: how can I retrieve the id of the dynamic TextBoxes? In the html page, there is a prefix in each of them and I don't want to use a loop.
In example:

```
 protected void DettOrdGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {...
          e.Row.Cells.Add(cellQta); //here i add a cell to the row of the grid
           ...
        }
```

in the html page:

```
    $(document).ready(function){
        $("#btnSaveProvvisorio").delegate("textbox", "change", function(){
            var jtbNumBollaQuin;
            jtbNumBollaQuin=$('#<%=myTextBoxQta.ClientID%>').text();
            alert("Valore quantita : " + jtbNumBollaQuin); 
        })
       }
```

The error is:

```
Compilation Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

 Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'myTextBoxQta' does not exist in the current context
```

Thank you!

```
Here the aspx.net code:
 protected void DettOrdGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {


...


myTextBoxQta = new TextBox();
                myTextBoxQta.ID = "myTextBoxQta";
                myTextBoxQta.Attributes.Add("nomeTextBox", "myTextBoxQta");
                myTextBoxQta.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                myTextBoxQta.Attributes.Add("onChange", "javascript:TotaliOrdDett();");
                myTextBoxQta.Style["text-align"] = "center";


i = e.Row.Cells.Count;
                i = i - 1;
                //Column label
                if (e.Row.RowIndex == -1)
                {
                    if (risultato > 0) 
                    {...
                    }
else //...add a textbox
                {


                    myOracleConnection = myDbClass.dbConnessione("myconn");
                    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cella: " + e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
                    myQuery = "SELECT QTA_NR, KG_LORDI FROM TABLE WHERE SOC='1' AND ORD=" + ordHidden.Value + " AND ROW_ORD=" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
                    qtaKgInseriti = myDbClass.EseguiSqlSelect(myQuery, myOracleConnection, qtaKgInseriti);
                    myDbClass.dbDisconnessione(myOracleConnection);


                    e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(myTextBoxQta);
                    cellQta.Controls.Add(myTextBoxQta);
                    e.Row.Cells.Add(cellQta);
                    //myTextBoxQta.Text = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
                    if (risultato > 0)
                    {
                        myTextBoxQta.Text = qtaKgInseriti.Tables[0].Rows[0]["QTA_NR"].ToString();
                        txtSumQta.Text = (Int32.Parse(txtSumQta.Text) + Int32.Parse(myTextBoxQta.Text)).ToString();
                    }
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(myTextBoxKg);
                    cellKg.Controls.Add(myTextBoxKg);
                    e.Row.Cells.Add(cellKg);
                    //myTextBoxKg.Text = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
                    if (risultato > 0)
                    {
                        myTextBoxKg.Text = qtaKgInseriti.Tables[0].Rows[0]["KG_LORDI"].ToString();
                        txtSumKg.Text = (Double.Parse(txtSumKg.Text) + Double.Parse(myTextBoxKg.Text)).ToString();
                    }


                    myCompValNr = new CompareValidator();
                    myCompValNr.ID = "myCompValNr";
                    myCompValNr.ErrorMessage = "<div style=\"font-size: x-small; text-align: center; color: #FF0000\">Please enter a number grater than zero!</div>";
                    myCompValNr.ControlToValidate = "myTextBoxQta";
                    myCompValNr.Type = ValidationDataType.Integer;
                    myCompValNr.Operator = ValidationCompareOperator.GreaterThan;
                    myCompValNr.ValueToCompare = "0";
                    myCompValNr.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
                    e.Row.Cells[i + 1].Controls.Add(myCompValNr);

                    myReqFvNr = new RequiredFieldValidator();
                    myReqFvNr.ControlToValidate = myTextBoxQta.ID;
                    myReqFvNr.Text = "<div style=\"font-size: x-small; text-align: center; color: #FF0000\">Field Qta cannot be null!</div>";
                    e.Row.Cells[i + 1].Controls.Add(myReqFvNr);


                    myCompValKg = new CompareValidator();
                    myCompValKg.ID = "myCompValKg";
                    myCompValKg.ErrorMessage = "<div style=\"font-size: x-small; text-align: center; color: #FF0000\">Please enter a number grater than zero!</div>";
                    myCompValKg.ControlToValidate = "myTextBoxKg";
                    myCompValKg.Type = ValidationDataType.Double;
                    myCompValKg.Operator = ValidationCompareOperator.GreaterThan;
                    myCompValKg.ValueToCompare = "0";
                    myCompValKg.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
                    e.Row.Cells[i + 2].Controls.Add(myCompValKg);

                    myReqFvKg = new RequiredFieldValidator();
                    myReqFvKg.ControlToValidate = myTextBoxKg.ID;
                    myReqFvKg.Text = "<div style=\"font-size: x-small; text-align: center; color: #FF0000\">Field Kg cannot be null!</div>";
                    e.Row.Cells[i + 2].Controls.Add(myReqFvKg);

                }





        }
```

Thanks Chris and other guys,
I found the solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSaveProvvisorio").click(function () {
                var i;
                var jtbNumBollaQuin;
                $('.MyTextBoxClass').each(function(i,v){
                    jtbNumBollaQuin = $(this).val();
                    alert("Valore quantita : " + jtbNumBollaQuin);
                });
            });
        });
```

and set  myTextBoxQta.CssClass = "MyTextBoxClass"; in the aspx.cs file
and ClientIDMode="Static" to the btnSaveProvvisorio button int the aspx file.

Thanks so much!!!
Igor

Comment: The ASP.NET control named myTextBoxQta doesn't exist on your page... it likely doesn't have a runat="server" on it.

Comment: Chris, I put the tag: myTextBoxQta = new TextBox();
                myTextBoxQta.ID = "myTextBoxQta";
                myTextBoxQta.Attributes.Add("nomeTextBox", "myTextBoxQta");
                myTextBoxQta.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                myTextBoxQta.Attributes.Add("onChange", "javascript:TotaliOrdDett();");
                myTextBoxQta.Style["text-align"] = "center";

Comment: Ahh, I see now. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data attribute`like

```
<textarea data-clientId="#<%=myTextBoxQta.ClientID%>" ></textarea>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function){
   $("#btnSaveProvvisorio").delegate("textbox", "change", function(){
       var jtbNumBollaQuin;
       jtbNumBollaQuin=$($(this).data('clientId')).text();
       alert("Valore quantita : " + jtbNumBollaQuin); 
   });
});// check end of document.ready()
```

Also check `id` `<%=myTextBoxQta.ClientID%>` exists in your page.

Answer (score 0):

1. The ASP.NET control named `myTextBoxQta` doesn't exist on your page... it likely doesn't have a `runat="server"` on the control's tag.
2. Use `.on` instead of `.delegate`.

   - Update *

After looking at your code, you should do this via CSS class to test your code works.

```
myTextBoxQta.CssClass = "MyTextBoxClass";
```

Then...

```
$(document).ready(function){
     $("#btnSaveProvvisorio").delegate("textbox", "change", function(){
         var jtbNumBollaQuin;
         jtbNumBollaQuin=$('.MyTextBoxClass').text();
         alert("Valore quantita : " + jtbNumBollaQuin); 
     })
}
```